# UIWebView change line spacing text

Tags: javascript, xcode, ios5, uiwebview

I'm looking for a javascript method or a way to change line spacing of text in a UIWebView.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Evan has answered the above question, but I have another on the same topic.

How can I query the source for the current line spacing value?

Comment: Where is the source coming from (web server, local file)? And can you modify it?

Comment: It's for a browser type app. It's all coming from the internet and I want to change the line spacing of text after the content is loaded into the UIWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject javascript into the `UIWebView`'s source by calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.

Javascript:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    rules = document.createTextNode('* { line-height: 20px !important; }');
style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet)
    style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
else style.appendChild(rules);
head.appendChild(style);
```

Objective-C (probably in `webViewDidFinishLoading:`):

```
NSString *js = /* The javascript above in a string */
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

---

To retrieve the `line-height` value of the first `h1` element on the page:

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    lh = style.getPropertyValue('line-height');
return lh;
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *js = /* The javascript above in a string */
NSString *lineHeight = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: Just looking for clarification on this line " line-height: 20px !important;" - the 20px can be replaced with a variable, right? And what does the !important mean?

Comment: Yes, "20px" is just a value I picked. You can insert it into the string using `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`. The "!important" is for overriding other `line-height` styles that are already present on the page.

Comment: One more question, how would you get the current line height from the source?

Comment: It depends on the element it is applied to. It could differ for different `p`, `h1`, etc. elements.

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say for h1.