# how to set height spacing 55 pixels for web view in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, spacing

Hey I'm new to iPhone and I have been trying to set height spacing exact 55 pixels for UIWebView. I can able to set using my below code :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
webView.opaque = NO;
[webView sizeToFit];
```

But i would like to know that is it possible to set height spacing in pixels for UIWebView in iOS 7. I have attached screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please create html for that and load in webview. IN html code you can set the space and height and width easily :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView change line spacing text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775527/uiwebview-change-line-spacing-text)

Comment: Thanks to all.. i will try to change in my backend server, bcos i am getting description in html code format.